# OData ASP.Net Core on GET with Id?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

I'm trying to `[EnableQuery]` on a route (User) with id as example if I do a :

```
GET /users/1?$expand=Character
```

I'd like to get the User with Id 1 with its Character but currently it returns me null on the character :

```
{"character":null,"id":1,"username":"Iterer","password":"motdepasse","characterId":1}
```

But on the (global) route to get all users :

```
GET /users?$expand=Character
```

I get the user's character as you can see :

```
[{"character":{"id":1,"name":"Name"},"id":1,"username":"Iterer","password":"motdepasse","characterId":1}]
```

Here is my controller's actions :

```
    // GET: api/Users
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public ActionResult<IQueryable<UserEntity>> GetUsers()
    {
        return Ok(_context.Users);
    }

    // GET: api/Users/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public ActionResult<IQueryable<UserEntity>> GetUserEntity(long id)
    {
        var userEntity = _context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (userEntity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(userEntity);
    }
```

Both use IQueryable interface but I still don't understand why it doesn't works, here is the full controller :

https://github.com/myerffoeg/gaium-api/blob/master/Gaium/Controllers/UsersController.cs

and my startup file :

https://github.com/myerffoeg/gaium-api/blob/master/Gaium/Startup.cs

Moreover, if you have some best practices to share it would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Try odata syntax GET /users(1)?$expand...

Comment: When I try a GET /users(1) or /Users(1) I get a 404.

Comment: Ok then ur missing your odata route prefix configured in startup like /odata/users(1)...

Comment: I added my MapODataServiceRoute with api as route prefix & I expand the ODataController on my controller but I still get a 404 with /users(1).

Comment: Well don’t use same prefix as your api controller template, try using prefix odata and the query /odata/users(1)

Comment: Same problem I tried removing all my controllers & remaking them but still 404 with Users(1) or users(1) (you can see modifications I have made on the repository).

Comment: Firstly verify then that /odata/$metadata works and builds edm as expected

Comment: The $metadata route works & my UserEntity is well built & the navigation property to the CharacterEntity is present (as well as the CharacterEntity is present).
The route odata/users?$expand works but not the users(1).

Comment: Sorry, you’ve gone wrong somewhere, this should work out of the box. Try following tutorial https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/asp-net-core-odata-now-available/

Comment: Now I've managed to make /odata/users(1) works but when I do a ?$expand=Character the Character is null but not on the /odata/users?$expand=Character I can't understand why.

Comment: The /users/1?$expand=Character works but the $expand doesn't works as expected (it expand but set the character to null, repository updated.

Comment: take a look at his github-repo: https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreOData

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Both use IQueryable interface but I still don't understand why it doesn't works

Well, the difference is that while to "non working" method *claims* to return `IQueryable<UserEntity>`:

```
public ActionResult<IQueryable<UserEntity>> GetUserEntity(long id)
```

the implementation returns single materialized `UserEntity` instance.

In order to match the claim, the implementation should be like this instead (basically the first method with `Where` clause applied):

```
return Ok(_context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == id));
```

Comment: By doing this I get a json array (with my character in it) [{...}] but I want it to be an object : {} how can i manage to do that ?

Comment: Well, the above is based on your method definition. I'm not quite familiar with OData, but from EF Core point of view, if you return materialized object, it's too late to apply operators on it like `expand`, `select` - they need access to the underlying query.

Comment: @Myerffoeg: Ivan Stoev is absolutely right with his point. If you call FirstOrDefault(); you´ve finished the DB-call. Just remove FirstOrDefault and everything will work as expected. Also refer to deferred execution to understand a little more of the how and why..

Answer (score 3):

The parameter name should be key instead of id i.e.

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get(int key)
    {
       return Ok(_repository.Get(key));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As described by Ivan, your code returns a single materialized Entity. You do need to return the `IQueryable<UserEntity>`, but as you said in your comment:

`return Ok(_context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == id));`

Will return an *Array* with a single entity, not what you want.

You need to tell OData that this query will only return zero or one entity using `SingleResult`:

`return Ok(SingleResult.Create(_context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == id)));`

This will return what you want: A single entity(no array), which $expand can be applied.